# Group by a column and enter value in a column based on another column in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my Data Frame:

```
         ID        Date    Value  Final_Value
    0   9560    07/03/2021  25
    1   9560    03/03/2021  20
    2   9712    12/15/2021  15
    3   9712    08/30/2021  10
    4   9920    04/11/2021  5
```

Here, I need to groupby ID and subtract 1st value and next value of `Value` column if ID is the same and the last occurrence of ID should be same as Value and enter in Final_Value. For instance, ID = 9560 the expected output is:

```
         ID        Date    Value  Final_Value
    0   9560    07/03/2021  25      5
    1   9560    03/03/2021  20      20
```

The expected output for whole Data frame is given below.

```
         ID        Date    Value  Final_Value
    0   9560    07/03/2021  25     5
    1   9560    03/03/2021  20     20
    2   9712    12/15/2021  15     5
    3   9712    08/30/2021  10     10 
    4   9920    04/11/2021  5      5
```

How could I achieve this?